# iText7 generated PDF tables missing bottom border

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext, itext7

I'm currently using C# to generate a PDF with tables of data inside but I am encountering a problem where all my tables do not have a bottom border.

E.g. [image: Missing Bottom Border]

I am quite positive the problem here is the lack of using the table.Complete() method given by the iText7 library but using this method returns an error saying 
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' which baffles me because without this method my table is generated perfectly fine in the pdf except without the bottom border. I have tried looking through iText7 documentation and I may just be blind but I am unsure whether its a problem with the code or my lack of understanding in the usage of tables in iText7.

Example code of its generation before it is added to the PDF

```
/* Test Table */
            Paragraph glueTitle = new Paragraph("Test");
            glueTitle.SetFontSize(15);
            glueTitle.SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
            DataTable glueData = sql.loadGlue();
            cellArrList = new List<Cell[]>();
            headerInfo = new string[]
            {
                "Sensitive Info Placeholder"
            };
            Table glueTable = new Table(headerInfo.Length, true);
            glueTable.SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
            glueTable.SetFontSize(8);
            for (int i = 0; i < headerInfo.Length; i++)
            {
                Cell cell = new Cell();
                cell.SetBackgroundColor(WebColors.GetRGBColor("dodgerblue"));
                cell.SetFontColor(WebColors.GetRGBColor("white"));
                cell.SetBold();
                cell.Add(new Paragraph(headerInfo[i]));
                glueTable.AddHeaderCell(cell);
            }
            foreach (DataRow row in glueData.Rows)
            {
                Cell[] cellArr = new Cell[headerInfo.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < headerInfo.Length; i++)
                {
                    int x = i;
                    cellArr[i] = new Cell();
                    cellArr[i].SetBorderBottom(new SolidBorder(1f));
                    if (i == 2)
                        x = 3;
                    else if (i == 3)
                        x = 2;
                    cellArr[i].Add(new Paragraph(row[x + 1].ToString()));
                }
                if (row[2].ToString().Replace(" ", "") != "")
                {
                    cellArr[1].SetBackgroundColor(ColorPickerPDF(CompareNumbers(length, row[2].ToString(), 1)));
                    cellArr[2].SetBackgroundColor(ColorPickerPDF(CompareNumbers(length, row[3].ToString(), 0)));
                    cellArr[3].SetBackgroundColor(ColorPickerPDF(CompareNumbers(width, row[4].ToString(), 1)));
                    cellArr[4].SetBackgroundColor(ColorPickerPDF(CompareNumbers(width, row[5].ToString(), 0)));
                    if (selection[1].Equals("1"))
                        cellArr[6].SetBackgroundColor(ColorPickerPDF(row[7].ToString().Equals("5")));
                    else
                        cellArr[6].SetBackgroundColor(WebColors.GetRGBColor("MediumSeaGreen"));
                }
                cellArrList.Add(cellArr);
            }
            foreach (Cell[] cellArr in cellArrList)
            {
                foreach (Cell cell in cellArr)
                {
                    glueTable.AddCell(cell);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Although you've already found a solution, I have a question: is it vital for you to use large tables (created with the `largeTable` set as true)?

Comment: @UladzimirAsipchuk I removed the header info within my code but some of the tables i'm making can go up to 15 columns and I was quite satisfied with how the layout was done by setting largeTable to true ( fixed layout , 100% width, etc ), summary of it was that I was a little bit lazy with finding the right layout settings for my tables to display the data and headers in proper spacing and the largeTable boolean did a decent job of it for me.

Comment: The reason I ask is that large tables are not so well developed as usual ones: there are some known open issues connected to them, so if it's not required, I would suggest that you use the usual one with some set parameters (width,fixed layout,...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the error to this, I was not aware of the need to add my pdf elements into the document element before making any additions to it and .Complete() returning null was a result of this. I'll leave my question here for any future users needing the reference.